# How to organize directory structure and write Makefile for external code

Tags: c++, makefile

I am starting a big project that include some external code. By now, I have a directory structure like this:

```
MyProject
|-- include
|    |-- FANN 
|    |    |-- src
|    |    |    |-- include
|    |-- eigen
|         |-- Eigen
|-- MyLibrary
|       +-- header1.H
|       +-- header2.H
|       +-- otherheaderN.H
|-- test
        +-- Makefile
        +-- test1.cpp
        +-- testN.cpp
```

I am using `include` subdir for external code, `MyLibrary` for my own headers files, and `test` for cpp test code.

I have FANN, Eigen, and other libraries. I am using their code directly, and I have not experience on including files, working with different directories, and stuff like that.

In the Makefile I have lines like this:

```
test1:
    g++ -I $(FANN) -I $(FANNINCLUDE) -I $(EIGEN) -I $(MyLib) test1.cpp -o test1
```

This is how I have solved it to compile, but don't know if it is not good to use various -I options. By example, look that I use FANN for the path to FANN/src and FANNINCLUDE for path/src/include; this is because I am including FANN/src/"doublefann.c" and it has a #include"config.h" (being config.h inside FANN/src/include). I am a mess!

Would you recommend a better way of organizing the files or it is good?
Am I doing it wrong in the Makefile?
Any other suggestion, would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you including a .c file?

Comment: @AnonMail it is because of the library: "simply include the file doublefann.c or floatfann.c in your project and everything should work" http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/help/installing-fann/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think including doublefann.c is a good idea.

To cope with this situation, you can compile all the external code into a shared (or static) library, and then include the headers into files in MyLibrary (or test) directory. After compilation, you can 'link' to the library.

If you have an option to switch from Makefile then CMake would be a better option. In my experience, using CMake to organize projects is easier than using Makefile.

Comment: I also think it is not good to include .c files, but I think it depends on the library. FANN has some .c files in the FANN/src dir and .h files in FANN/src/include and in the .c files (which they recommend to include in programs) the includes are made using `#include"header.h"`. Don't how could I manage it to work other way :(